# Open next error file in the integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

How to jump to the next error file and line position from the errors reported in the integrated terminal in VS Code.

CTRL + Click will open the file,  but what the keyboard shortcut to jump automatically to the next one without using the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
editor.action.marker.nextInFiles
```

default binding is <kbd>F8</kbd>.  That will go to the next problem in open files.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> will cycle between problems in the current file only.

Comment: This way will loop through the errors recognized by VS Code, and they are different from the reported ones in the terminal, for example if I build a custom project using command line in VS Code, any way to use the errors in the integrated terminal instead.